# Не работает YII2 валидатор на хостинге

Tags: php, yii2

Если сайт работает на локальном сервере, то валидация проходит нормально. Но если мы запускаем на веб сервере nginx + apache, профессионально настроенном, то валидатор выдает false, если мы передаём значения 'user_id = 12 , или любое другое

Версия PHP, одинаковая.

```
['user_id', 'string', 'length' => [1, 15]],
```

Почему?

Comment: Почему Вы применяете length для int? Проверяйте, что приходит в модель.

Comment: @ilyaplot, валидатор трактует `12` как строку же.

Comment: конечно, он же преобразовывает.

Comment: @ilyaplot Оно не играет роли, по моему. И если даже передавать string значение, то всё равно не будет проходить валидацию на веб-сервере, а на опенсервер(локальный веб-сервер) , будет.

Comment: Не понятно как передается значение, приходит ли в модель, отрабатывает ли сценарий, какие версии php локально и на сервере?

Comment: Версия PHP, одинаковая. 5.6

Comment: Стоп, похоже вы правы

Comment: Почему тогда на локальном веб-сервер работает? А можно ли в валидаторе проверять int?

Comment: решение ['user_id', 'number', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 15],